# How do I order my Custom Filter Attributes

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I'd like to control the order that the filters are run, is this possible?

```
[LogRequestFilterAttribute]
[ApiKeyRequestFilterAttribute]
```

I always want to Log the Request first, then the security check, is this possible? The Priority property seems to be related to execution before/after the Global filters.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Is it ASP.NET MVC? These are your custom filters which are delivered from ActionFilterAttribute (FilterAttribute)? If yes - you can use Order property on them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.order(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Nope, just a plain vanilla asp.net web project super-charged by ServiceStack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Request and Response filter attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) have a **Priority** property which you can override that lets you specify the sort order upon which the filters are fired.

This is the sequence of events from when the first filter is executed, from ServiceStack's [Order of Operations wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations):

```
  ...

  5. Request Filter Attributes with Priority < 0 gets executed
  6. Then any Global Request Filters get executed
  7. Followed by Request Filter Attributes with Priority >= 0
  8. Action Request Filters (New API only)
  9. Then your Service is executed with the configured IServiceRunner and its 
     OnBeforeExecute, OnAfterExecute and HandleException custom hooks are fired
  10. Action Response Filters (New API only)
  11. Followed by Response Filter Attributes with Priority < 0
  12. Then Global Response Filters
  13. Followed by Response Filter Attributes with Priority >= 0
```

Any time you close the Response in any of your filters, i.e. `httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest()` the processing of the response is short-circuited and no further processing is done on that request.